# newbie to jquery - fadeout doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Can anyone understand why this simple code doesn't work:

```
    <script src="/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

        $(document).ready(function() = {
        $('div.FadeOutMessageBox').click(function () { $(this).fadeOut("slow"); });
        };
        //]]>
    </script>

    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

                <div id="FadeOutBox" class="FadeOutMessageBox">
                     thank you bla bla
                     click this message to make it go away
                </div>
...
```

it suppose to put some simple div on the page which fades out when clicked. but nothing happens when I click this div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() = {
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

edit : also you need to make sure you close any `(` or `{` that you open.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('div.FadeOutMessageBox').click(function () { $(this).fadeOut("slow"); });
    });
</script>
```

Try this!

> 1: You accidently added a = in between function () and {
>
> 2: "$(function() {" is actually the same as "$(document).ready(function() {" So it is a great shortcut!
>
> 3: You missed the ) in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the last `)` so ready is never closed:

`});`